# useEffect as componentWillUnmount

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I am trying to refactor an old class component into a functional component with hooks and have got stuck with a `componentWillUnmount`

Previously the code had this:

```js
 componentDidMount() {    
    this.isDropdownMounted = true;
  } 


  componentWillUnmount() {      
    this.isDropdownMounted = false;
  }
```

My solution was to use to use a `useEffect` with a cleanup function but despite it 'appearing' to work it failed code review and I can't seem to find a better solution. I've read about potentially using a `useRef` but haven't stumbled across a similar use case just yet.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    isDropdownMounted = true;

    return function cleanup() {
      isDropdownMounted = false;
    };
  }, []);
```

Any ideas what I can try?

Comment: "failed code review" is pretty subjective. Your code seems to be a pretty correct replication of the previous code

Comment: What is your goal setting isDropdownMounted = false when component will unmount? This make no sense.

Comment: Instead of isDropdownMounted I recommend you to use "useRef" hook.

Comment: Not entirely sure what the goal of that was. I just started and was asked to refactor the component and this was the outcome. the full file is here: https://gist.github.com/SerdarMustafa1/f888cdb0c45c9f30211db6bee4819296. Can you elaborate on how I could use `useRef` for this? @lissettdm

Comment: @SerdarMustafa, sure, see my answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React doesn't remember isDropdownMounted variable. It will be recreated on each render. It will be better to use useRef hook to set value in useEffect and remember it on the next render.

```
const isDropdownMounted = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
    isDropdownMounted.current = true;

    return function cleanup() {
      isDropdownMounted.current = false;
    };
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 2):

`useEffect` lets you return a cleanup function that will run whenever your component unmounts.

NOTE: It will also run whenever something in the dependency array of the `useEffect` changes. It assures you that you'll always get a "fresh" effect.

[React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup) on `useEffect` with cleanup.

Here is the example they use:

Using classes:

```
componentDidMount() {
    ChatAPI.subscribeToFriendStatus(
      this.props.friend.id,
      this.handleStatusChange
    );
  }

componentWillUnmount() {
  ChatAPI.unsubscribeFromFriendStatus(
    this.props.friend.id,
    this.handleStatusChange
  );
}
```

Using hooks:

```
useEffect(() => {
  function handleStatusChange(status) {
    setIsOnline(status.isOnline);
  }
  ChatAPI.subscribeToFriendStatus(props.friend.id, handleStatusChange);
  // Specify how to clean up after this effect:
  return function cleanup() {
    ChatAPI.unsubscribeFromFriendStatus(props.friend.id, handleStatusChange);
  };
});
```

Here is a working example:

```js
function App() {

  const [boolean,setBoolean] = React.useState(true);
  
  const toggleBoolean = () => setBoolean((prevState) => !prevState);

  return(
    <div>
     { boolean ?
         <Component1/>
       : <Component2/>
     }
       <button onClick={toggleBoolean}>Toggle</button>
     </div>
  );
}

function Component1() {

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Component1 has mounted...");
    return () => { console.log("Component1 has unmounted...")};
  },[]);

  return(
    <div>Component1</div>
  );
}

function Component2() {
  return(
    <div>Component2</div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I tried to do in my solution, but apparently not correctly.

Comment: You probably got a bug somewhere. But that is the way to go. What happened? Shouldn't `isDropdownMounted` be a state, thus, be updated through a `setState` call ?

Comment: IMO it worked but the feedback I got was: "I'm not convinced this even works, I feel like it would break because it's not declared as a const, let or var. I can see you're translating from the old component style as directly as possible, but this can just be a useState const in the new version."

Comment: I guess it should be a `useState`, shoudn't it?